# Oracle OPAM REST API checkout method returns an http 409 code

Tags: java, rest, oracle-opam

I am trying to use OPAM REST API

I've wrote several java methods that are working correctly (although some details took me some time to figure out), but now I am stuck in this one

```
https://host:port/opam/account/accountUID/checkout
```

which returns me a 409. Any clues?

I am following the [same approach as described in this post](http://gskblogs.blogspot.com.br/2014/04/a-tour-of-oracle-privileged-account.html) (in the end of it there's an example on how to write a java HTTP request)

It seems to be related to the user at OPAM that I use to authenticate in the client, which seems not to be authorized to checkout the password. If it's the case, what permission shout I grant to this OPAM user in order to do so?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the privileged account must have explicit permissions for the user that my REST client is using to authenticate

[image]

this way, I can successfully check out the account using opam client

[image]